# Migrate Maven project Liferay 6.2 to 7.2

Tags: maven, migration, liferay

I have to migrate my maven liferay project from version 6.2 to version 7.2. 
I would like to use the Liferay IDE program and use the Liferay Upgrade plan, but my project is not a SDK project. When I launch the planner, it tells me that I must choose an SDK project and my project is not. It's a maven one.

How can I convert my maven project into an SDK project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used the Liferay ide to upgrade maven modules from 6.2 in the past and we never used the sdk project. When you are on the "Liferay code upgrade" tool, simply select your maven project and it should be able to analyze it. If you want to upgrade many/all modules at the same time, you should have a parent pom with  section in it and all of those will be analyzed.

Pretty much everything did work for us, but we had a bit of work to fix the maven dependencies when we used properties or dependanciesManagement to manage our version.